# how to change marker activation on scroll in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have google map with multiple markers.

And i want to active different marker activation on user scroll.

Map should not scroll just change activation of marker.

[demo link is here](http://austin.eater.com/maps/best-new-austin-restaurants-heatmap)

I check all the google map events but i can't fount any scroll activity on map

Comment: Guess google maps itself doesn´t provide this event. But for me it sounds that you are thinking in the wrong direction. The Markers are just laying **ON** the map, so you would probably have to bind your scroll event on .window` or sth else. Catch the event and iterate through the marker array. But I can´t give you a guarantee for that, haven´t done it myself.

Comment: Ah now I have took a look at you provided demo link. Yeah the event is bind to the div as far as I could see in 5 sec´s . So i guess my comment above should give you the hint in the right direction.

Comment: it may be different div but map is scrolling with details. if it's different divs then it map should also scroll with details

Comment: Nah... you should take a deeper into the API... The Scroll Event has NOTHING to do with the fact that the map scrolls... The way I described in my first comment, should be the way to go here. While scrolling you go over the marker array. ForEach "selected" array element, you call google maps `.setView()` . This will look similar to the demo.

Comment: If you would provide a page with sample data, I could better help you.

Comment: i am trying to make something like demo but i don't know from where, i should start? i just have demo link only

Comment: Of course I did. But this is not a provided page with sample data.... Create a working fiddle (jsfiddle.net) so I can play around. But I´m pretty sure that i´m right here. And one thing, instead of `setView()` i guess it is `.setCenter()` or sth like this

Comment: Sorry buddy, but I won´t write the entire code for you. In general it is a pretty easy task, start here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/?hl=en and go further.

Comment: thanks for it, i will start from here.